Update Survey123 media via Python (not via republishing)
Using the example in the Developers.ArcGIS.com documentation I am trying to update a Survey123 form's media file pythonically. My modified version of the example code is downloading an empty Zip file.
import arcgis
import tempfile
from arcgis.gis import GIS

gis = GIS("pro")
itemID = "[some item-id]"

surveyManager = arcgis.apps.survey123.SurveyManager(gis)
surveyId = surveyManager.get(itemID)
surveyProp = surveyId.properties
print(f"\nSurvey Properties: --->{surveyProp}")

surveyItem = arcgis.gis.Item(gis, itemID)
print(f"\nSurvey Item --->{surveyItem}")

tmpdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
downloadFolder = tmpdir.name
fileName = "Form_Media.zip"
savedZip = surveyItem.download(save_path=downloadFolder, file_name=fileName)

The forms owner (who has much higher AGO Org privileges than me) is also getting an empty zip when they run the code.
Is there something missing in my code?
